# Difference between the Active Directory User class' E-mail-Addresses attribute vs. the Proxy-Address attribute

Tags: active-directory, exchange-server

I am using the Proxy-Address attribute as a primary means of determining the user's email address (where I only care about the addresses prefixed with "SMTP:" or "smtp:" and, furthermore, I am using the address prefixed with an uppercase SMTP to determine the primary address - this is not 100% reliable, but it's a limitation of an existing system).

I was informed that this attribute (Ldap-Display-Name = mail, CN = E-mail-Addresses) can be used as a fall back, to determine a user's email addresses (if no smtp addresses can be found under the Proxy-Address attribute(s)), but I can't find examples of multiple addresses for this attribute.

The MSDN documentation indicates that the E-mail-Address attribute should be `"the list of email addresses for a contact"`. In all the examples I am finding, there is only a single address and it is not prefixed with "SMTP:" or "smtp:" so I am unsure how one would determine the primary email address unless the reality is that the mail attribute should only ever be a single address?

Comment: Are you operating against a standalone or hosted exchange installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find the following useful, from http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2005/01/10/350132.aspx

> E-Mail Address Attributes
>
> Exchange stores and uses information about the e-mail addresses of a
>   recipient in the following attributes:    proxyAddresses
>
> This is the main attribute where e-mail address information is kept.
>   When you open the properties of a recipient in Outlook and look at the
>   "E-mail Addresses" tab, you are looking at this attribute. This is a
>   multi-valued string containing all the addresses that represent the
>   recipient. Each value must have the following format:
>
> ```
>   type:address
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>   SMTP:nospam@online.microsoft.com
> ```
>
> When the type is in uppercase letters, the address is considered to be
>   the primary address of that type and it is used as the default reply
>   address of that recipient. When the type is in lowercase letters, the
>   address is considered a secondary address and is used to resolve
>   addresses during e-mail delivery, allowing the same recipient to
>   receive e-mails directed to different e-mail addresses.

Comment: thanks :) ... (now I'm just satisfying my min char requirement)

Comment: Wasn't there a bounty on this? I answered before it expired!

Comment: no I never put a bounty on this.. sorry if you thought there was a bounty :/